# for loop inside of body of email lua script

Tags: email, for-loop, lua

Basically, I have several devices I need to pull data from. I get multiple emails when the temperature measures are under or over the set limits. I would like to have a `for` loop to include all current devices states that are under or over limits into one email.

```
body = for device_name, 1 do 
  device_name++ -- I get error here because unexpected symbol near 'for'
  "Device Name: " ..device_name.. "\nDevice Location: " ..device_location.. 
  "\n--------------------------------------------------------------" .. 
  "\nCurrent Temperature: " ..temperature.." F".. "\nTemperature Limit: ("..
  t_under_limit.. "-" ..t_over_limit.. " F)" .."\n\nCurrent Humidity Level: " .. 
  humidity .. "%".. "\nHumidity Limit: (" .. h_under_limit.. "-" ..h_over_limit.. "%)" 
  .. "\n\n-------Time Recorded at: " ..os.date().. "-------"})
end, -- end for
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously noted, there is no `++` operator in Lua. Also, the syntax for the `for` loop is different from what you wrote.

I would like to add that the big concatenation afterwards would be much more readable using `string.format`. Here is an enhanced version of your code, in the form a a function taking a table devices parameters in input, each element being a subtable:

```
local report_model = [[
Device Name: %s
Device Location: %s
--------------------------------------------------------------
Current Temperature: %d °F
Temperature Limit: (%d-%d °F)
Current Humidity Level: %d %%
Humidity Limit: (%d-%d %%)

-------Time Recorded at: %s-------]]

function temp_report(devices)
  local report = {}
  for i=1,#devices do 
    local d = devices[i]
    report[i] = report_model:format(d.name, d.location,
      d.temperature, d.t_under_limit, d.t_over_limit,
      d.humidity, d.h_under_limit, d.h_over_limit,
      os.date())
   end
   return table.concat(report)
end
```

Comment: so would the body = report_model?

Answer (score 2):

there is no variable++ syntax in lua. you need to do

```
variable = variable + 1
```

also, you can't assign some for loop construct to a variable. so this statement

```
body = for device_name, 1, ...
```

isn't valid. maybe you meant...

```
local body = ""
for device_name = 1, 1
    device_name = device_name + 1
    body = body.. "my custom message stuff here"
end
```

Comment: yes thats it, sorry lua does a few things differently that I am trying to adapt to

Comment: The loop you write here does not make any sense: it is executed only once.

Comment: i didn't have much to work with, given the code sample above. i was more interested in showing him the syntax rather than correcting the logical mistake in the example provided.